# angular 2 trigger a modal open outside of router module

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I want to trigger the hiding/showing of a div in a component template outside the router outlet by clicking a button in a component template within the router outlet:

app component

```
`<div class="content col-md-10 container-fluid">   
    <company-add-form></company-add-form>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>`
```

company-add-form component

```
`<div>
    <p>Make me showwwww</p>
    <button class="btn">Close</button>
</div>`
```

company-page component (which will render inside router-outlet)

```
`<div>
    <button class="btn">Open company add form</button>
</div>`
```

Thoughts

- Usually theres a pretty consistent parent to child relationship but because router outlet sits in between you can't just use ViewChild.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not bind with components that are added by the router.

You should use a shared service [@angular/injectable](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html) view [component communication](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html) for examples from the @angular [cookbook](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/).